# C# WinForm custom control events not trigger

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, events, controls

I am developing a project in visual studio using Winform.

A part of project contains displaying pdf files. I am using opensource library installed via nuget - [PfiumViewer by Pieter van Ginkel](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer)

The loading and everything works fine but no clicks events are firing.

I have checked the events with all other control it works fine but no events are fired of pdfviewer.

Below is my code to load the viewer. I'm even selecting the pdfviewer.

```
        pdfViewer1.Document?.Dispose();
        pdfViewer1.Document = OpenDocument(file_path);
        pdfViewer1.Select();
```

Here is the code I want to fire with the mousemove event

```
               private void pdfViewer1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = (pdfViewer1.Renderer.Page + 1).ToString();
    }
```

Below is the code generated in my designer.cs

```
this.pdfViewer1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pdfViewer1_MouseMove);
```

What am I missing or what I need to do to trigger the event?

Comment: are you clicking on the pdf viewer before moving the mouse...is it the focus object?

Comment: Yes the scrolling of the PDF is working properly

Answer (score 0):

The `PdfViewer` class contains two child-controls, a TreeView that shows the bookmarks and the `PdfRenderer` part, where the pdf is shown. If you want events that are happening in the renderer, attach your method to the events of the `PdfRenderer`, which is exposed as the `Renderer` property.

If you want to show the page number, you can try the `DisplayRectangleChanged` event, which is fired when the visible part within the renderer is changed. This is also how it is done in PdfiumViewers example project.